# I am trying to edit text in unity but it keeps giving null reference exceptions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class text : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text MT;
    public GameObject TM;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TM = GameObject.Find("Menu_Text_1");
        MT = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
        MT.text = "HELPPP";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

to change text in unity but it keeps returning null reference exceptions even though I know that the the game object has a text component.

I have tried adding a component, but it said it already exists and nothing I looked up helped as it looked like they were doing basically the same thing but it was working for some reason, and I am going insane. (BTW I know what a noll reference exception is its just acting weird.)

Comment: OT - Do yourself a favour and give those fields (`MT` and `TM`) better names e.g. `text` and `gameObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
TM = GameObject.Find("Menu_Text_1");
MT = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
```

Instead, try:

```
TM = GameObject.Find("Menu_Text_1");
MT = TM.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
```

As an aside, `Text` is a legacy `UnityEngine.UI` component, which has been more or less replaced by [TextMeshPro](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-textmesh-pro).

Hope I helped, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

No need to assign references through hard-coded strings `TM = GameObject.Find("Menu_Text_1");.`

You can assign the text directly from the Unity Editor, and because you've set the type to be `Text` (`public Text MT;`), you will already have the attached component.

Have you assigned them in Unity Editor?

Additionaly,
There are several issues with coding practices in your code.
One of them is giving proper names to variables and classes. If you want to learn, [visit this](https://unity.com/how-to/naming-and-code-style-tips-c-scripting-unity).

Comment: Its like those because these are place holder variables The real variables have proper names but I Have these variable to simplify the trouble shooting process.